# Is there an practical SQL interface that feels like excel?

Tags: database, sql, spreadsheet

I have used SQL Server Managment Studio, and Azure Data Studio, and MySql Workbench.

I wouldn't consider myself an expert on using any of those programs. However, it seems like I still do a large portion of basic work typing out SQL statements.

Is there an interface that would allow me to pull up a table, delete and edit entries, in a manner similar to excel?

If not, Why? Has the market just not responded, or is there an inherit reason this would not work?